# Div under another div while not intended

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress theme and I'm stuck on something.

I have a div on the side with these styles:

```
#sidediv{
    width: 20%;
    height: 71%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

and:

the "content" div with these styles after the sidediv

```
#main{
    background-color: #a70202;
    color: #FFF;
    min-height: 71%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the `#main` div is partly underneath the `#sidediv`.
The content is next to it as it should be but the padding is not applying and if the background-color is removed from the `#sidediv` the background-color of the `#main` is showing underneath

This is the website i'm working on http://vba.durfoptevallen.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#main{
  background-color: #a70202;
  color: #FFF;
  min-height: 71%;
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Added `float:left` and `width: 80%;`

On that url, you have another problem:

`http://vba.durfoptevallen.nl/wp-content/themes/Vastgoedbeleggingen_Theme/js/small-menu.js?ver=20120206` is not loading (404)

Comment: That places the #main on the bottom of the page

Comment: I added the width as well

Comment: Thanks, Don't know why I havn't checked that.. I've been messing with it for an hour, must be because of monday. Thanks!

Comment: I also noted you have a problem with `small-menu.js` which is not being found.

Comment: Excellent, then you may close mark question as answered :)